# linked list java, can't find symbol error

Tags: java

[this is my main class, i'm trying to have print out the words from the other class, it is giving me the can't find symbol error, I verified the name of my string, but I still can't find the errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code ? Maybe you misspelled a class name or maybe there is an issue with the scope of one of your variables. A lot of reasons can be the cause of this error.

Comment: In the future -- post your code as code-formatted text, not as an image. How can anyone copy and paste an image into their IDE and run it as a program?

Comment: Also post your full error messages.

Comment: Then please look at [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)